# ODI Studio won't start on Windows 11 - tried multiple JDK versions and compatibility mode, any ideas?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have installed ODI Studio (fmw_12.1.3.0.0_odi.jar) on a Windows 11, but I can't get it to start. It loads approximately 5% and then closes without displaying any error or log. However, there is no issue when running it on Windows 10.

I have tried different versions of JDK (jdk1.8.0_211, jdk1.8.0_351, jdk1.8.0_361) and also running ODI Studio in compatibility mode for Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle Support, Oracle Data Integrator Studio **12.2.1.3.0** is certified on these Windows versions:

- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 8.1
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 7
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 2019
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 2016
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 2012 R2
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 2012
- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 10

The latest version (**12.2.1.4.0**) is also certified on:

- Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 2022
- **Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) 11**

So it appears that Windows 11 is not certified with the ODI version that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, ODI 12.1.3 ran with Windows 11. I discovered the actual error when running ODI from the cmd console:

> ODI Exception in
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
> from bund.

According to the documentation, the ODI Studio version is important for me, because the repositories version in my current client is 05.01.02.07 (Repositories created or upgraded using ODI 12.1.3.0.1).

For inexplicable reasons, with the Windows update, my personal ODI configuration was damaged, so a reinstallation and resetting of the ODI configuration was necessary (not only reinstallation). In my case, I had to delete the folder:

> C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\odi.